# Problem after linking Firebase to a React Native app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I am trying to link my react-native app to firebase and work on the `auth` module.

I followed the steps of the installation in https://rnfirebase.io/

It works when I run `npx react-native run-android`

But when I use `expo start` to work on the pre-production app I always get the error `you attempted to use a firebase module that is not installed firebase.app()`
[image]

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding.
``cd android && ./gradlew clean``
then
``react-native run-android``

Comment: I tried cleaning the app but it doesn't work, running {react-native run-android} on an emulator works perfectly but when I run the app using {expo} I get this error. I re-built this project fro more than 3 times and it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this problem for while, after solving it, I would like to share my answer.

The library https://rnfirebase.io/ does not work with a managed workflow like Expo, so be sure to use the bare workflow to work with the library.